# Two binding parameters for textfield in blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I have text field in blazor which is bind with verification function using FluentValidation. I would like to also have an onChange parameter as I want to bind this textfield also with SVG graphics to draw scaled rectangle using onChange textfield parameter but I'm getting error. I read that bind-Value and onChange shouldn't be together but I'm still new to Blazor and don't know how else to bind onChange action to SVG to redraw rectangle and validate input at the same time.

```
<MudForm Model="@model_input" @ref="@form">
<MudCardContent>
<MudTextField @bind-Value="model_input.Width" Validation="@(inputValidator.ValidateValue)" 
     For="@(() => model_input.Width)" Immediate="true" Label="w [mm]"
 onChange="ScaleGraphics"/>

<MudTextField @bind-Value="model_input.Height" Validation="@(inputValidator.ValidateValue)"
     For="@(() => model_input.Height)" Immediate="true" Label="h [mm]"
 onChange="ScaleGraphics"/>
</MudCardContent>
</MudForm>
```

Rectangle SVG

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 @mainDwgWidth @mainDwgHeight">
 <rect width="@scaledWidth" height="@scaledHeight" x="10" y="10" style="fill: skyblue; stroke: cadetblue; stroke-width: 0.2;" />
</svg>
```

Function to update rectangle

```
@code {
private double mainDwgWidth = 200;
private double mainDwgHeight = 100;
private double scale { get; set; } = 0.0;
private double scaledWidth = 50.0;
private double scaledHeight = 50.0;

private void ScaleGraphics()
{
    scale = Math.Min(mainDwgWidth / model_input.Width, mainDwgHeight / model_input.Height);
    Console.WriteLine("scale: {0}", scale);
    scaledWidth = model_input.Width * scale;
    scaledHeight = model_input.Height * scale;
    StateHasChanged();
}
}
```

I was checking the console and nothing is even written so it doesn't even call ScaleGraphics(). Anybody with working solution? Much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about MudBlazor controls, but you should be able to bind to the `OnInput` which may met your needs.

Comment: I tried with noInput but no difference.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: no error. It's just nothing happens when i change values in the textfields.

Comment: If OnInput isn't triggered, then there are no safe ways of doing it with MudBlazor.  The shackles of using someone else's framework. If you were using the standard Blazor Input controls, it would be a different answer.